# Syntax of exporting kid3-cli

Tags: terminal, tags, export, command-line-interface

I type this command in the terminal  `kid3-cli -c export -c "./tags.txt" -c "CSV more unquoted"`
or I try it in the script:

```
kid3-cli -c export \
         -c  "./tags.txt" \
         -c "CSV more unquoted" \
```

Writes this:

```
Usage:
export P S [T] Export to file
               S = Format name
```

When I do it interactively in the same order, it works.

```
kid3-cli> export "./tags.txt" "CSV more unquoted"
kid3-cli>
```

What am I doing wrong and how to build the syntax correctly so that it works from the command?

[manpage](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kid3/kid3/kid3-cli.html#cli-import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
kid3-cli -c "export tags.txt 'CSV more unquoted'"
```

Comment: So it was the use of the `''` and `""` characters? Probably would be good to note that in this answer.